# Undefined output when adding inputs in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to make a BMR calculator as a homework assignment. I think i figured most of it out, but i get "undefined" as output in my output field. Here is the code:

```
<input class="boks" placeholder="vekt i kg" id="vekt" type="text">

<input class="boks" placeholder="høyde i cm" id="hoyde" type="text">

<input class="boks" placeholder="alder" id="alder" type="text">

<button id="beregn" onclick="utregning()">Regn ut din BMR</button>

<input class="boks" placeholder="Din BMR" id="output" type="text" 
readonly="true">
```

js:

```
var konstant = 66.5;

var vekt = parseInt(document.getElementById("vekt").value);

var vektutr = vekt*13.75;

var hoyde = parseInt(document.getElementById("hoyde").value);

var hoydeutr = hoyde*5.003;

var alder = parseInt(document.getElementById("alder").value);

var alderutr = alder*6.755;

var sum = +konstant + +vektutr + +hoydeutr - +alderutr;

function utregning() {

document.getElementById("output").value = sum;

}
```

Comment: You are getting the values from the input fields at page load, before they have a value.

Comment: You need to put all your variable inside your function, otherwise they're getting their value before the user does anything.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get all the values from input inside the function, because the code outside the function will execute before calling `utregning` and at that time the value of the input field will be empty

```js
var konstant = 66.5;



function utregning() {
  var vekt = parseInt(document.getElementById("vekt").value);

  var vektutr = vekt * 13.75;

  var hoyde = parseInt(document.getElementById("hoyde").value);

  var hoydeutr = hoyde * 5.003;

  var alder = parseInt(document.getElementById("alder").value);

  var alderutr = alder * 6.755;

  var sum = +konstant + +vektutr + +hoydeutr - +alderutr;

  document.getElementById("output").value = sum;

}
```

```html
<input class="boks" placeholder="vekt i kg" id="vekt" type="text">

<input class="boks" placeholder="høyde i cm" id="hoyde" type="text">

<input class="boks" placeholder="alder" id="alder" type="text">

<button id="beregn" onclick="utregning()">Regn ut din BMR</button>

<input class="boks" placeholder="Din BMR" id="output" type="text" readonly="true"> js:
```

Comment: Rookie mistake on my part, forgot that i need to make the function, you know, a function. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

try this code: i tried and it's works fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>
            My Web Page
        </title>

    <script>
        function utregning() {
var konstant = 66.5;

var vekt = parseInt(document.getElementById("vekt").value);

var vektutr = vekt*13.75;

var hoyde = parseInt(document.getElementById("hoyde").value);

var hoydeutr = hoyde*5.003;

var alder = parseInt(document.getElementById("alder").value);

var alderutr = alder*6.755;

var sum = +konstant +vektutr +hoydeutr - alderutr;

document.getElementById("output").value = sum;

}   
    </script>

    </head>

<body>

<input class="boks" placeholder="vekt i kg" id="vekt" type="text">

<input class="boks" placeholder="høyde i cm" id="hoyde" type="text">

<input class="boks" placeholder="alder" id="alder" type="text">

<button id="beregn" onclick="utregning()">Regn ut din BMR</button>

<input class="boks" placeholder="Din BMR" id="output" type="text" 
readonly="true">

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: This answer would be more useful if it explained _why_ it works fine.

Comment: ok @auxTaco.if the user puts all values inside function he is secure that all variable are initialized in correct way...sorry, i am new...